# Javascript upload files without any HTML code, Forms, inputs etc

Tags: javascript, django, dhtmlx

I'm new in webdevelopment and especially in javascript. My taks is to make use of DHTMLX library in the project I'm working on.

I have a problem with uploading files to django server. Right now I'm using DHTMLX javascript library, There is DHTMLXToolBar on mine site with a button. I want to upload files by clicking on this button. but Mine code do not show me any window to choose a file / files (many praferably).There are not any html code whatsoever regarding this.

I have tried with hidden forms, even hidden iframes with forms, bare javasctip, but still nothing.

Mine js code

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");   
filesToolbarObject.attachEvent("onClick", function(id) {
    if (id == "new"){

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("action", "");
        form.setAttribute("id", "playlist_form");
        form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "filesToUpload[]");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("id", "filesToUpload");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "file[]");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("multiple", "");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("onChange", "makeFileList();");

        var crfcTokenField = document.createElement("input");
        crfcTokenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        crfcTokenField.setAttribute("name", "csrfmiddlewaretoken");
        crfcTokenField.setAttribute("value", '{{ csrf_token }}');

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        form.appendChild(crfcTokenField);

        iframe.name = "myTarget";

        // Next, attach the iFrame to the main document
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
          iframe.style.display = "none";
          document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        });


        iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
            $('.upload').show();
        });                             
        form.target = iframe.name;
        form.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(form);
    }
});
```

Server side:

```
for fileToUpload in request.FILES.getlist('filesToUpload[]'):
    fileType=get_file_type(fileToUpload.name.split('.')[-1])
    if fileType:
        newFile = Media()
        newFile.type = fileType
        newFile.ext = newFile.name.split('.')[-1]
        newFile.size=fileToUpload.size
        newFile.file=fileToUpload
        newFile.name=fileToUpload.name
        newFile.save()
```

Comment: Where is the code that should upload the files?

Comment: well, that's it, this is all I've got. as said praviosusly, I'm a noob :/ but eager to learn ;)

Comment: Ok. Well that is the problem, you only have a form that posts. You need a server side script to actually upload what is in the form.

Comment: I have a server side code just fine, i just need to make it open the "browse files" window, which will make a file list. Server side and post data won't be a problem I will handle it

Comment: You need to add a `<input type="file"/>` to your form.